# How to deploy DevExpress to server?

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, iis-6, devexpress

Hello I am needing to deploy a project using DevExpress controls to an IIS 6.0 server. The project loads fine and until I add in the DevExpress controls. When trying to load the site I get the error

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'DevExpress.Web.v9.3, Version=9.3.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified

What am I doing wrong? I've tried installing the controls on the server and also just copying all of the assembly dlls to the bin/ folder of the application but I can not get this error to go away. How do I get it to work?

Comment: I also have to add all the references to get it to work. Have you figure out what's the specific dll you're missing? My app went up by 100MB...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up going into Visual Studio and then selecting all of the DevExpress references and setting "copy local" to true.

Answer (score 6):

The specific error means that it is looking for version 9.3 of DevExpress.Web assembly.

For server deployment, you only need the runtime dlls. A list of the necessary dlls are in the help file under the deployment topic:

['deployment' results from search.DevExpress.com](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=deployment&p=T4|P5|0&d=128)

[Brendon Muck's free 'DX Server Installer' tool](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2010/02/05/free-tool-devexpress-server-installer.aspx) is also very handy (as mentioned by @JHappoldt)

One last note, please be aware that you do not need to copy the design time dlls to your web server. These files are only meant to be used in Visual Studio. Also, it against the [EULA] to distribute these. One simple way to figure out the design time dlls is that they usually end with '.Design'

For example: 'DevExpress.XtraReports.v9.3.Design' (This should not be deployed)

Comment: good point about the .Design bit. But that tool does not work for me. It crashes on both my dev environment and on the server

Comment: Could you do me a favor and post a comment on that blog post please? Brendon can help you figure out the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Within a Web Publish (AKA WPP) you can use my [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DevExpress.WPP). Just install it into the web project (<strike>Web Sites and</strike> Azure is also supported). And you don't need to set 'Copy Local' to `true`.

Comment: Web Site projects do not contain an option like 'Copy Local' as far as I know. I added your nuget package, but didn't see the dll's in the output. Do my project need to be a Web Application, or Web Site is just ok?

Comment: I'm sorry I hadn't tested web sites thoroughly. Just the installation of the package. But what 'output' do you mean? Build or Publish?

Comment: Unfortunately, web sites are not supported. Only web applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official tool to do a thin install on a server, however a community member wrote a very [useful tool](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2010/02/05/free-tool-devexpress-server-installer.aspx).